# Nome da conexão com entity está fora dos padrões

Tags: c#, entity-framework, conexão

Sempre que eu altero o banco de dados, preciso deletar o edmx e recriá-lo, pois o update from database não está atualizando. Até aí tudo bem. O que passa que agora ele criou uma conexão com o nome totalmente fora do padrão. Ficou assim:

```
win-mdsk429aa7b.V99_Web.dbo
```

Antes era só V99_WebEntities. Esse nome aparece quando eu dou um New Conection e aparece na compbo onde tenho as conexões. Como deleto essa conexão para voltar ao normal, como era antes? Se não alterar a conexão, terei que alterar todo o meu sistema, fora de cogitação.

Quando eu deleto o edmx, eu também excluo a linha do meu web.config referente ao edmx deletado.

Comment: acho ser isso o nome do computador. Onde eu vejo isso? Onde fica esses nomes?

Comment: No deploy não funcionou. Eu só tenho a pasta bin, o arquivo .svc, o Package.config e o web.config. A pergunta é: Como o deploy sabe que há uma conexão, com um owner errado? Como meus arquivos transportaram isso? Onde posso alterar? Tem como?

Comment: Deletei o edmx e uma referência a ele continua sem dar erros. Dei um F12 em cima dele e mostrou um edmx, como Metadata. Como apareceu se eu deletei?

Comment: Deletei o edmx e uma referência a ele continua sem dar erros. Dei um F12 em cima dele e mostrou um edmx, como Metadata. Como apareceu se eu deletei? Ele cria umas pastas ocultas e adiciona esse arquivo: V99SuporteTecnico.Models.V99_WEBEntities.cs

Comment: Isso só acontece com o web service, de eu deletar o edmx e ainda continuar funcionando no meu svc.cs sem que eu tenha adicionado outra vez. Não sei como, mas deletei o arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preciso entender bem dessas coisas. Foi resolvido. Eu tenho uma solution com vários projetos, sendo um deles, um Web Service. Como no atual momento eu venho trabalhando no Web Service, ele está como meu projeto principal e tem seus componentes abertos no IDE, tais como o .svc e a interface. Sempre que crio uma nova conexão, me dá esse erro. O que fiz. Fechei o WS, abri o meu projeto principal mesmo, setei para o projeto de start up e qundo fui criar um novo edmx, funcionou como antes. Não sei porque mas era o WS.

Me precipitei. Voltou a dar o erro. Não tinha dado. Mas eu havia feito algo errado. Alterei e quando fui fazer outra vez, deu o erro já citado.

Descobri que o nome que ele monta é o nome da máquina onde está o banco. E não estava funcionando no IIS, devido a isso: Quando eu publiquei, tive que publicar o web.config devido a uma alteração que fiz(nunca mando o web.config, mas foi necessário desta vez). Só que para mim, o web.config estava apontando um ip onde está o banco. Só que esse IP é mascarado e é lido apenas de fora pra dentro. Logo, com o web.config tyendo esse IP ele não reconhece(de dentro), aí ele não acha o banco porque o IP não existe pra ele. Passei para localhost e aí funcionou. Agora sim, tudo resolvido.